# Writing packet data to file with DPDK results in drops (even at traffic speeds <200 Mbps). What is the bottleneck?

Tags: networking, pcap, dpdk

I'd like to capture and store 100% of traffic from 1 single port in PCAP format with DPDK at line rates greater than 10 Gbps for an extended period of time. The NIC I'm using is a Mellanox Connectx-5 and the system is running Centos 7.4. The storage filesystem is XFS. I have over 100 cores to utilize and very large storage capacity that's in a hardware Raid 0 configuration. I've tested the storage with multiples processes (1-10) that can write to it at a combined rate of 1GB/s-~8GB/s. I've tried several tests to achieve line rate packet storage but always seem to have at least 0.2%-20% packet drops at traffic speeds from 150 Mbps to 4000 Mbps.

The first test I did was with DPDK's testpmd and pdump. This was found to be not a good solution as a very large percentage of packets are dropped at the hardware interface.

I then tried a modified basic forwarding application that instead of forwarding the packets writes individual packets using standard PCAP headers and fwrite. The pcap files are incremented when reaching a threshold (1 million packets). With these test the best throughput rate I was able to capture and store with 0% drops was 100 Mbps, which is incredibly slow for my needs.

I then tried the same previous test but with an mmap'd file and rte_memcpy, and a separate thread that will have a number of mmap'd files ready to go using producer/consumer logic. For short bursts at high throughput speeds, this seemed to work great but overtime the performance would degrade, and was not much better than simply using fwrite.

I then tried DPDK's ring library to distribute packets to multiple threads that will each handle writes for their own files with fwrite. And the best rate I was able to capture and store traffic with 0% drops was around 1000 Mbps with 10 cores receiving and writing to separate files. Any more than 10 cores, and performance seems to degrade and drops increase. I also found that with this setup, I'm able to capture all of the packets, but the drops are just shifted instead of being at the interface to being at the rings where packets are enqueued/dequeued for writing. Here's the snippet that does the writes

```
static inline int
write_pkt(struct rte_mbuf *mbuf, FILE* out_file)
{
  uint8_t *pkt;
  uint32_t pkt_len = mbuf->pkt_len;
  struct pkt_header *pcap_hdr = (struct pkt_header *)
            rte_pktmbuf_prepend(mbuf,
                (uint16_t)sizeof(struct pkt_header));
  pcap_hdr->pkt_length = pkt_len;
  pcap_hdr->pkt_length_wire = pcap_hdr->pkt_length;
  pkt = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbuf, uint8_t *);
  fwrite(pkt, 1, pkt_len+pcap_header_size, out_file);
  return 0;
}

static int
do_packet_write(uint8_t in_client, FILE* outFile){
    int i;
    struct client   *cl_in = &clients[in_client];

    struct rte_mbuf *pkts_burst[PACKET_READ_SIZE];
    const uint16_t nb_rx = rte_ring_dequeue_burst(cl_in->rx_q, \
                                                        (void **)pkts_burst, PACKET_READ_SIZE, NULL);
    if (nb_rx == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    captured[in_client] += nb_rx;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_rx; i++){
        write_pkt(pkts_burst[i], outFile);
        rte_pktmbuf_free(pkts_burst[i]);
    }
    return (int)nb_rx;
}
```

My goal is to reach 0% packet loss at 50000 Mbps and I'm very far from there. What is the bottleneck in processing the writes? How can I fix it so there are no drops?

I've tried other tweaks to increase performance, playing with packet read size (8-64), increasing the number of 1GB hugepages, copying the packet data to large buffers and then writing the buffers, all of which have not seemed to help. Increasing the vbuf size with set_vbuf. Adding a layer of workers between the interface RX core and the Write cores to prepend PCAP headers. I'm really desperate to understand this problem at a deeper level.

Comment: I've not used `DPDK` but I've had to do a production grade commercial product that is _very_ similar to what you're trying to do [albeit at a lower data rate, but I had to do a lot of measurement to verify no packet loss] using write vs mmap and `PF_PACKET`. I'll [eventually] try to post an answer with some suggestions, but it would help to know a few more things first. What is the value of `PACKET_READ_SIZE`? ? What is value of `getsockopt(fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF)`? When you did `mmap` for write, did you use `madvise`?

Comment: If you did a dummy load for input, (e.g. fake the `rte_ring_dequeue_burst` to provide data instantly), possibly throttled to max expected input rate, what was the sustained write rate? I had a timestamp/benchmark routine that called `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)` and instrumented my code so that it kept an in-memory ring queue for events (e.g. EVT_PKT_ARRIVED, EVT_PKT_QUEUED_FOR_WRITE, EVT_PKT_DEQUEUED_IN WRITE_THREAD) for any "events" that are significant to you. If my code detected an anomaly, it would force a dump of the events [or from ctrl-c].

Comment: Thank you for the reply and your advice. To answer your questions, PACKET_READ_SIZE is 32 currently. I actually do not use getsockopt to receive packets, DPDK provides these interface specific drivers to receive the packets directly from the hardware queues and bypass the kernel. I'm not familiar with madvise but it looks like a great tool to use in my situation. I'm not sure about the sustained write rate with a dummy load, I'll try that next.

Comment: Dpdk-pdump is enhanced to work with multiple thread from 19.08 and above. So based on test-pdump use case with default 4  rx thread, you redirect 4 pcap file minimum. But any syscall using fwrite will lead to overhead. Can you try the same test with multiple pdump threads instead of single thread for all rx queue. You can also enhance dpdk pdump to capture headers only and try using mmap write too.

Comment: as mentioned in my earlier comment, there is old but a good article on the same. this might help you `https://www.napatech.com/dpdk-packet-capture-pdump/`. from my end, I been exploring the use of `rte_mbuf_refcnt_update` instead of memcpy from Primary application to Secondary (PDUMP), in my humble opinion this will reduce the overhead of rte_pdump_init from doing memcpy

Comment: the topic is related to `dpdk` and `pcap` and not related `linux` or `networking`. Both https://stackoverflow.com/users/5123537/martin-bri%c5%a1iak and https://stackoverflow.com/users/11502612/milanbalazs believes this is not the case, with reason `This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains`. Surprsiing when the tag `networking` is removed and not added.